# change language of page when nav link clicked

Tags: laravel, localization

I want to develop my site in two languages and want to change the language on the nav link click.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App;
use Lang;


class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function setLocale($locale='en')
    {
        if (!in_array($locale, ['en', 'ja'])) {
            $locale = 'en';
        }

        Session::put('locale', $locale);
        redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('locale/{locale?}', array('as'=>'set-locale', 
            'uses'=>'LanguageController@setLocale'));
```

**Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Session;
use Config;
use App;

class Locale
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale=Session::get('locale', Config::get('app.locale'));
        App()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Views**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/locale/en') }}">English</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/locale/ja') }}">Japanese</a>
</li>
```

**this is how i am using language key**

```
{{trans('home.Services')}}
```

where I have created two `home.php` in both `ja` and `en` in lang and set the language there

when I click the nav link the page just goes to `localhost/../locale/ja`. I don't know where I m making a mistake. I have also set the kernel middleware as `\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class`, . thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You may be fault on kernel.php. Just for sure, on 
`$routeMiddleware`  check that you added `'locale' => \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,`

Comment: yes i have added that

Comment: You said you added it on kernel `$middleware`. It should be on `$routeMiddlewere`

Comment: i have that on middleware as App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class, and on routemiddleware as u said

Comment: remove `App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,` from `$middleware` array. just add `'locale' => \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,` on `$routeMiddleware` array

Comment: did that too same problem. when i click on navlink i just get redirected to /locale/ja with no content on page

Comment: oh, I see, you have a route problem. This is because, you did not used **url() **properly. I think you change **url()** with **route()**.

Answer (score 1):

On `kernel.php > routeMiddleware` add this.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
//... other lines of code.    
    'locale' => \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
];
```

And change the view to,

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('set-locale', 'en') }}">English</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('set-locale', 'ja') }}">Japanese</a>
</li>
```

I am not sure, this is an issue or not, change the route to,[just add a `'/'`.]

```
Route::get('/locale/{locale?}', array('as'=>'set-locale', 
            'uses'=>'LanguageController@setLocale'));
```

Comment: tried it same problem. do i need to set a prefix in route and add all the other routes to view inside that group?? i cant understand why i m being redirected to /locale/ja when i click on japanese

Comment: added \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class in my middleware and it worked. thanks for your help though

Comment: Dont know, in my kernel, its available (by default.)